# I don't understand Python concurrent.futures

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to execute the `do_stuff_parallel` function with multithreading.

```
def do_stuff_parallel(par1, par2, par3, par4, par5):
    print("test1")
    print(str(par1))
    print("test2")
    if(.. == ".."):
        ...

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    futures = set()
    for LinkedConnector in FuncGroupTask.Connectors:
        f = executor.submit(do_stuff_parallel, par1, par2, par3, par4, par5)
        futures.add(f)
```

It needs to execute the `do_stuff_parallel` function every time with 5 parameters at once.

Now its entering the `do_stuff_parallel` method but it only prints "test1" and never par1 or "test2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it a bit wrong. `Executor.map()` maps every single item of your list to workers, and you will get exceptions. Your function expects five arguments but you only send one.  With concurrent.futures the exception is there stored in a future, and only raised if you try to retrieve the result. This will show you the exception:

```
def do_stuff_parallel(par1, par2, par3, par4, par5):
    print("function entered")


par1=par2=par3=par4=par5 = 42

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    for _ in range(1,10):
        f = executor.map(do_stuff_parallel, [par1, par2, par3, par4, par5])
        for q in f:
            print(q)
```

This results:

```
TypeError: do_stuff_parallel() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'par2', 'par3', 'par4', and 'par5'
```

You need to deliver a tuple instead and then unpack it in your function:

```
def do_stuff_parallel(args):
    print(args)
    return(42)


par1=par2=par3=par4=par5 = 43

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    for _ in range(1,10):
        f = executor.map(do_stuff_parallel, [(5,6,7,8,9),(3,4,5,6,7)])
        for q in f:
            print(q)
```

Now you can access your paramerters as args[0], args[1] etc.   If you cannot change the worker function interface, you can create a wrapper, where your proxy worker calls the real worker:

```
def proxy_worker(args):
    return real_worker(args[0], args[1] ....)
```

And of course if you do not intend to map anything, then use `executor.submit()` instead of `map()`. This would allow you to send multiple arguments if your intention is just to launch the worker several times.  Map is used as a helper to map an iterator to workers and you might not need it here at all.

With `executor.submit()` you can keep your interface as it was:

```
def do_stuff_parallel(a,b,c,d,e):
    print(a)
    return(42)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    futures = set()
    for _ in range(1,10):
        f = executor.submit(do_stuff_parallel, par1, par2, par3, par4, par5)
        futures.add(f)
```

Comment: How do i create a tuple with my arguments?

Comment: Just put them in parentheses ().   But please do clarify first where is the iterable in your program. If you only have one tuple to be sent to workers, then you should consider executor.submit().   Map is only useful if you have an iterable, in your case returning tuples of five items.  What you do now is actually just a sequential execution, as map blocks until your worker completes. You submit one task, wait for it to complete, then submit it again etc.  Check the difference between map and submit and see which one you actually need.

Comment: Submit would also be able to pass multiple arguments instead of just one.

Comment: i dont have a iterable, so i think i need to use: `executor.submit(do_stuff_parallel, par1,par2,par3,par4,par5)`

Comment: Indeed. And then you can pass arguments as you did before. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: You will want to collect the future objects to a set as shown above if you want to access the results, know if there were any exceptions or indeed know when all your workers have completed.  If you do not care, then there is no need to store the future object either.

Comment: Thanks you so much! you are a hero!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166818/discussion-between-sandervtilburg-and-hannu).